# What feature selection technique would you recommend for selecting many features (in the thousands)?

Tags: classification, feature-selection

I have a data set that has a large number of features (~8k features) and I want to limit the number of features so my model does not overfit but performs relatively well. I have mix of categorical and numeric features. I am trying to use these features for classification. Does anyone have any recommendations for methods that I can use that are not too computationally expensive? If you can steer me towards some literature or have an examples available that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you done basic cleaning to remove all null features?

Comment: Yes, I have indeed.

Comment: What is the overall purpose of the predictive model? Some more context in the question might be helpful

Comment: So, the majority of the features are text classification features that are output from different embeddings from different models. We've combined these features together with other categorical and numeric attributes about the entities in our data set into a large dataframe with the purpose of predicting a binary response variable.The overall purpose is determine which features should be selected to create a model that performs well but doesn't over fit.